# Error while trying to build an APK file for React Native project

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, react-redux

> ****Task** :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
> *FAILURE*: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:**
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource compilation failed
> \mobile\flyfoot2\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\drawable-mdpi\assets_images_nour.png: AAPT: error: failed
> to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

```
 \mobile\flyfoot2\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\drawable-mdpi\assets_images_nour.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
```

Comment: > Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

Answer (score 5):

You Using splash screen in java file. and the splash screen image maybe.. ".png" file. so just change the file name ".png" to ".jpg".....

main background in splash screen should be in .jpg...

//this will help you to Removing error

Comment: [link](http://example.com) @Sajib thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a folder named assets/images/ in your root project directory and a image file nour.png like assets/images/nour.png in it.

First change this png file to jpg. you can use this https://png2jpg.com/ image convertor tool. Then after delete nour.png from assets/images and paste your downloaded nour.jpg file here.
You need to change the image extension png to jpg in your code somewhere too, means if you write nour.png somewhere in your code change it to nour.jpg.
Then delete the build folder android/app/build. Now everything is done, run command

```
./gradlew assemblerelease
```

in android folder.

Comment: My app was building fine for iOS (expo: eas build) but failed for Android. The Android error does not tell you much & I spent quite a bit of time searching. This answer helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Delete All drawable dir

rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*

& also change the formate of Your Image

Then Try to generate Again, Hope your Problem will solve.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this error because some of your Icons or Images are not in the PNG extension. Make sure all of your Icons and Images are in PNG.

Answer (score 0):

I have download some icons in .webp format and just change their extention to .png I thought it will work but it hasn't work, that why I were unable to release .apk. latter I convert all those images icons to .png and it works for me.